# ER_PARSE_ERROR on mysql sequelize array of string data type

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

For following code below:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    providerIds: { type : DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)}

  }
```

I am getting following error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[], `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `ReviewId` INT' at line 1
    at Query.formatError (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:175:14)
    at Query._callback (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:49:21)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:94:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
    at Protocol.write (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/media/mydata/projects/jobcuejs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:96:28)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:526:21)
```

What's wrong am I doing?

```
>mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.28, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

An array of type, e.g. DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.DECIMAL). Only available in postgres.

Visit http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/?highlight=array#array